# getting the list of files to be copied using cp command in a C program

Tags: c, bash

I have a bash command

```
"cp -rf "TEMP_DIRECTORY"/* "USER_DIR"/";
```

I am using that inside a C program.

`TEMP_DIRECTORY` and `USER_DIR` are defined using `#define`.

I want to get the list of files inside `TEMP_DIRECTORY`. Can I do that with the above approach?

Comment: Did you mean `"$TEMP_DIRECTORY"` and `"$USR_DIR"`? Did you really mean to put quotes around `"cp -rf "`?

Comment: @jxh - `TEMP_DIRECTORY` and `USER_DIR` are defined in the program by means of `#defines`

Comment: Real code, please. Complete commands.

Answer (score 0):

If we treat the provided line of code as the actual code fragment you intend to use to perform the desired task, the answer to your query is *no*.

Assuming:

```
#define TEMP_DIRECTORY "/tmp"
#define USER_DIR "/home/joe"
```

Then the provided statement is simply an expression representing a string constant, and by itself performs no action. GCC with sufficient warnings will tell you that:

> ```
> .code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
> .code.tio.c:5:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
>  "cp -rf "TEMP_DIRECTORY"/* "USER_DIR"/";
>  ^~~~~~~~~
> ```

To make the command take effect in your C code, you will need to pass the string to a function, such as `system()` or `popen()`.

```
const char *cmd = "cp -rf "TEMP_DIRECTORY"/* "USER_DIR"/";
system(cmd);
```

However, since `system()` and `popen()` use the shell to execute the commands, they are susceptible to command injection attacks. If your `TEMP_DIRECTORY` and `USER_DIR` actually contain shell environment variables that you want expanded, it is better that you expand them yourself with `getenv()`, form the complete paths, and then invoke the command via `fork()` followed by one of the `exec()` variants. If you need the glob expansion, there is the POSIX utility `glob()`, or you can walk the directory yourself using functions from `<dirent.h>`.

Comment: Not a good practice to teach -- if one's temporary directory is `/uploads/$(rm -rf ~)/hello.d`, behavior would be unfortunate. Much better to avoid `system()`; even if one is going to use a shell, passing parameterized content out-of-band from the script text (in either an environment variable or separate argv entry) is far safer.

Comment: An example of the latter, still using a shell (bad for performance) but passing content through the environment (good for security) would be: `setenv("temp_directory", TEMP_DIRECTORY); setenv("usr_dir", USR_DIR); system("cp -rf \"$temp_directory\/*" \"$usr_dir\"/");`

Comment: ...or, to avoid the shell altogether: `execvp("cp", char[][]{"cp", "-rf", TEMP_DIRECTORY "/.", USR_DIR "/"});` -- obvs., needs to be invoked from a forked subprocess if intending to keep the parent alive. Had to remove the `*` since that that doesn't work without a shell involved, but `/.` will serve the same use.

Comment: (Yes, a path *compiled into script text* will presumably be vetted by a human, but real-world `cp` invocations frequently aren't, and use names that come from `readdir()` or other unvetted / manipulable sources).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree using the shell to execute the command is unsafe if the goal is to use environment variable substitution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Do you have an answer for the [c] tag that addresses these issues that I can link to?

Comment: Eh? I didn't say that "using the shell to execute the command is unsafe if the goal is to use environment variable substitution". Quite the opposite: Using environment variable substitution is one of the *safe* ways to pass an argument into a shell, as opposed to the unsafe practice, demonstrated in this answer, of substituting literal content into a string passed to `system()`.

Comment: That's not the *only* safe practice, just the first one that came to mind. As another example (no environment variables involved!) `execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "cp -rf -- \"$1\" \"$2\"", "_", TEMP_DIRECTORY, USR_DIR, 0)` uses a shell but is safe (from shell injection vulnerabilities), because the values are out-of-band from the code.

Comment: ...unfortunately, the C tag isn't my usual haunt (haven't done C professionally for a significant amount of my time for nearing on 20 years now), so I don't have any suggestions handy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you are misinterpreting my intent. I am talking about the attacker setting the environment variable to some command instead of a simple string, thus injecting the command.